# Python get variables from string after decoding with cryptography

Tags: python, string, variables, cryptography

I'm programming an decryption on a file with sign-in information.
When I decrypt it, I end up with the info in a string.
This is the piece of code:

```
decrypted_message = encryption_type.decrypt(original)
testing = decrypted_message.decode("utf-8")
print("test: ", testing)
```

The output is:

```
test:  ip = "192.168.xxx.xxx", username = "xxx", password = "xxx"
```

How do i get the ip, username and password out off this string?

I can still change the output if it needs to be changed for a certain method.
Also I use the decode because otherwise I end up with b' before the output (which I know is bytes but I don't know how to use).

Comment: `testing.ip`?  what does `type(testing)` show?  What does `help(testing)` show?  What do `hasattr(testing, "__getitem__")` show? Based on how it prints I don't think your `testing` is a plain old string at all, I think it's some kind of object

Comment: Where is the encrypted data coming from, can you control the plaintext format before the encryption? The best way would be to make it e.g. json, but you can also use regex to deal with the current format.

Comment: @2e0byo considering what's said about bytes and usage of decode, it's quite safe to conclude that it's a plain string.

Comment: @2e0byo type(testing) prints <class 'str'>

Comment: @bereal yes I can change the plaintext before encryption and I need this information to login on a device.

Comment: Okay, I was completely wrong, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I changed the plaintext before encryption to a json:

```
{"ip": "192.168.xx.xx", "username": "xx", "password": "xx"}
```

Now that it's a json, I was able to print the variables after a parse.

```
settings = json.loads(testing)
print(settings["ip"])
```

So I now have a solution for my project.

Comment: Good! when the delay is up (I think it's 48 h), you should accept this as the answer so the questin is closed :)

Comment: Yeah I saw I had to wait 48h, thx for the help btw!

Answer (score 0):

If your string is literally as shown in your question the:

```
s = 'ip = "192.168.xxx.xxx", username = "xxx", password = "xxx"'
print(s.split()[2][1:-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If your output really is a string, something like this would parse it:

```py
a = 'ip = "192.168.xxx.xxx", username = "xxx", password = "xxx"'
parsed = dict(x.replace('"', "").split(" = ") for x in a.split(", "))
# {'ip': '192.168.xxx.xxx', 'username': 'xxx', 'password': 'xxx'}
```

But as noted in the comments you are *much* better off storing the data in json in the first place:

```py
import json
s = json.dumps(dict(ip="192.168.1.1", username="me", pass="xx"))
encode(s) # dummy fn
decoded = json.loads(decode(s))
# decoded is a dict
```